# Android custom control rendering issue

Tags: android, controls, clipping

I have the following custom control as per below details

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:background="@null"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/primary_text"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/txt_9999"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_sequence" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="numDescription"
        android:textColor="@color/material_dynamic_secondary10"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

</RelativeLayout>*
```

And the usage in a fragment

```
*<com.example.remote_dslr.EditNumber
    android:id="@+id/txtBtnDelay"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:key="p_BtnTime"
    android:layout_marginTop="6sp"
    custom:numIco="@drawable/ic_ring"
    custom:numMax="10"
    custom:numMin="1"
    custom:numUM="@string/txt_btnPressTime"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnReset"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnReset"/>*
```

The issue is that the bottom side of the textView in the custom control is clipped
[image]

Can anyone help support me in solving this issue?

Comment: Could you please try to use vertical LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout for your custom view?

Comment: Hi, I have test it and the result is the same. I have noticed that if I try to change the font size the size is not changing.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong. Can you show the full XML? The fragment and also the parent of the fragment (everything).